# Can I tear down a roof with a torch?

Tags: roof

Can my friends and I use a torch gas cutter to cut into the roof, and dismantle everything by sections?  I imagine there will be some concrete layering underneath and such.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Very small pictures, but if I'm seeing them correctly, that's a standard shingle roof which means it'll be over wood sheathing.

So no, using a flame cutter would be a substantially bad idea.  Unless you want the building to burn down, that is.